# Firebase prompts invalid json files when importing

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key-value

I'm trying to import data from json file into firebase but is showing "invalid json files" error.

This is the structure of my data:

```
[{"id":101013, "effectiveTime":"2002-01-31 00:00:00", "active":1, "moduleId":900000000000207008, "conceptId":126813005, "languageCode":"en", "typeId":900000000000013009, "Term":"Neoplasm of anterior aspect of epiglottis", "caseSignificanceId":900000000000020002},
 {"id":102018, "effectiveTime":"2002-01-31 00:00:00", "active":1, "moduleId":900000000000207008, "conceptId":126814004, "languageCode":"en", "typeId":900000000000013009, "Term":"Neoplasm of junctional region of epiglottis", "caseSignificanceId":900000000000020002}]
```

Any help would be well appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: How exactly are you importing this data??

Comment: I copy and pasted that string into a text file and it imported into the Firebase console correctly.

Comment: @Jay actually this json file is quite big.. it has around 1 crore rows... i am not able to import the intire file...

Comment: I am sorry you are having difficulties. Posting a question regarding a problem that's not duplicatable isn't going to lead to an answer. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668477/firebase-invalid-json-data-or-key-values-key-values-can-t-contain-o/42142475

Answer (score 2):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Adding on to Abhilash's answer, as the link above states: 
"If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127."

I had issues due to not saving my JSON file as UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue myself and what has helped is to change the encoding from UTF-8 with BOM to UTF-8.
You can do it for example in Sublime Text easily.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue and it might be two reasons.

1) your keys having ascii charecter 0-31 , 127 because firebase doesnot take this charecters as keys so make sure there are none of these charecters are in your firebase key or json key which is going to be firebase key.

2) problem with your json format use https://jsonformatter.org/ to validate the json data

Answer (score 0):

For reference,  I used http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm to convert a CSV file to JSON.  I then opened it up in Notepadd++, selected Encoding>Convert to UTF-8, saved, and it imported FINALLY!

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble manually converting the encoding type. Atom was saying it was already in UTF-8. So, an alternative is to export your database as JSON (create a test row if empty), then copy paste your data into the file. Crude, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with firebase.
My visual studio code editor is already in UTF-8 encoding format.

I solved the problem by:
Removing all special characters like periods (.) dash (-) underscore (_) slashes (/). Even if the strings is in quotes (""), it would still pose this problem.
I hope it helps some one having this problem