# How to solve Firebase - Invalid JSON data or key values. Key values can’t contain $ # [ ] / or

Tags: json, firebase, import

I know this question is duplicated but I still didn't find a solution for this..

Now I have an excel file as I converted this `csv` file to `JSON` file which contains `URL` to be as the below `JSON` Simple File:

```
[
{
    "First category level": "House",
    "Username": "Agent",
    "Picture URL": "https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/large_1574371860125983298.jpeg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/1574371963155915788_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720201765576925_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719641933844005_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720201702322421_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719671933648120_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720172054688102_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719711282962795_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/1574371976127814840_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719681510756892_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719721007832197_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/1574371980135907454_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719791550205986_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/157437198155029656_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719771029730786_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/1574371977262742584_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719841816940326_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/157437198935074321_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/157437198262102534_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719871045113443_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719921325866659_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719881907505281_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719862107386915_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/157437198853335430_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/1574371994716586575_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720001564968705_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/1574371994121122874_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719971677244500_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720222026002810_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720211496018484_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/1574372016638875820_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743719991920927875_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720021268623750_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720031938529177_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720211547065240_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/1574372008668788440_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/15743720101063489670_large.jpg, https://aradi.online/files/11-2019/ad3419/1574372012215551459_large.jpg",
    "Latitude": 31.87732437,
    "Longitude": 35.85965251,
    "Email": "info@aradi.online",
    "AOL Reference Number": "AOL-00022110103429",
    "Title": "280m-1Floor-3Bed-3Bath",
    "Size in M2": "280 m",
    "Property for": "Sale",
    "Price": "340,000 JOD",
    "Rental Price on Ad": "",
    "Building Condition": "Used",
    "Sell Price Per M2": "",
    "Rent Monthly Price per M2": "",
    "Rent Installment Value": "",
    "Rent Contract Payments": "",
    "Payment Method": "",
    "First Installment": "",
    "Number of Installment": "",
    "Installment Value": "",
    "Contact Type": "Owner",
    "Owner Name": "شركة الطيف لخدمات القيمة المضافة",
    "Broker Name": "",
    "Contact Number": "(962) 786-303090",
    "WhatsApp Link": "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=962786303090&text=%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%8E%D9%8E%20%F0%9F%91%8B%20.%20%D8%B4%D9%81%D8%AA%20%D8%A5%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%20House%20%F0%9F%8F%A0%20%20%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89%20%D9%85%D9%88%D9%82%D8%B9%20%D8%A3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B6%D9%8A%20%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%86%20%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%86%20%D9%88%20%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B6%20%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9%20%D9%88%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%B1%F0%9F%93%A3%20%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%AA%20%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86%20236m-1Floor-3Bed-3Bath%20%D9%88%20%D8%B1%D9%82%D9%85%20%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B9%D9%8A%20AOL-00022110103429%20%E2%9C%8D%20%D9%88%20%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%A8%20%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B3%D8%B1%F0%9F%93%9E%20%D8%A3%D9%83%D8%AB%D8%B1%20%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%87%20.",
    "Listing Key": "AOI-3419-136515",
    "Country": "Jordan",
    "Province": "Amman",
    "Area": "Amman",
    "Address": "مرج الحمام",
    "Bedrooms": 3,
    "Bathrooms": 3,
    "Villa/House Floors Number": 1,
    "Built Year": 2004,
    "Villa/House Finishing": "Deluxe",
    "Villa/House Furnished": "Furnished",
    "Villa/House Living Room Number": 1,
    "Villa/House Guest Room Number": 2,
    "Villa/House Kitchen Type": "Separated",
    "Villa/House Main Bathroom Type": "Bathtub",
    "Villa/House Lot Size": "1014 m",
    "Villa/House Balconi Number": 2,
    "Villa/House Terrace Size M2": 44,
    "Description": "منزل مستقل مكون من طابق ارضي وتسوية   للبيع \n طريق المطار  خلف مدارس العالمية\n  منطقة فلل جميع الخدمات\n مساحة الأرض 1014 م البيت على شارعين\n مساحة الطابق الأرضي  280م مع ترسين \nمكون من 3 غرف نوم واحدة ماستر و 3 حمامات و معيشة وصالون كبير \n ثلاث مداخل للبيت\n حديقة وكراج سيارات كبير \n-مساحة التسوية 240م بحاجة الي تشطيب \nمدخل مستقل للتسوية\n بير ماء 30 م \n البيع بداعي السفر \n السعر قابل للتفاوض بعد المعاينة",
    "Villa/House Features": "Storage, Air Condition, Water well, Water Heating, Central Heating, Abajor, Double Glass, Intercom"
  },
.......................
]
```

I figured that fire base doesn't accept special Characters like this `/` as it's a part of `URL`,

So there's any solution to Store something like these types of data format?..

Note that I figured this link:

[Firebase - Invalid JSON data or key values. Key values can’t contain $ # [ ] / or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668477/firebase-invalid-json-data-or-key-values-key-values-can-t-contain-o)

but didn't find a solution...

I also have alot of empty keys like this `""` in this `JSON` file I supposed that I replaced it with a `String`...

I hope this would be clear enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have keys like "Villa/House Kitchen Type"

It contains a character that it's not supposed to

Comment: thanks alot for your answer I'll try this and I'll give you my feed back :)